# how to create global file object in java?

Tags: java, eclipse, file

suppose i want to read 1st line in one method and 2nd line in another method , then how to read? how to access file globally?

```
class File{
private static void createFogDevices(int userId, String appId) throws Exception{
   File file = new File("/home/madhu/Desktop/data.txt");
   BufferedReader reader = null;
   reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    FogDevice cloud = createFogDevice(reader.readLine());
}
private static void addMobile(int userId, String appId) throws Exception{
   FogDevice mobile = createFogDevice(reader.readLine());
  }
 }
```

please help,i am getting error in reader.readLine() in addMobile method.

Comment: why dont you make it global in the class?

Comment: can you please do it? i am getting error

Comment: can you put in the whole code here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you can pass additional parameters path, and line number.
If you use java 8. Please see the following example for small files:

```
private static void addMobile(int userId, String appId, String path, int lineNumb)     throws Exception{
        String mobile =Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(path)).get(lineNumb);
    }
```

If you use java 7. Please see the following example:

```
private static void addMobile(int userId, String appId, String path, int lineNumb)     throws Exception{
    String infoString;
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path))) {
        for (int i = 0; i < lineNumb; i++) {
            br.readLine();
        }
        infoString = br.readLine();
    }
}
```

If you would like to make BufferedReader and File as global variables you can use the following example:

```
public class File {
private static java.io.File file;
private static BufferedReader reader;

static {
    try {
        file = new java.io.File("/home/madhu/Desktop/data.txt");
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(String.valueOf(file)));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static void createFogDevices(int userId, String appId) throws Exception {
    FogDevice cloud = createFogDevice(reader.readLine());
}

private static void addMobile(int userId, String appId) throws Exception {
    FogDevice mobile = createFogDevice(reader.readLine());
}
}
```

If you want to read from 6 to 8 lines you can use the following code:

```
String line;
    try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get("G:\\B\\1.txt"))) {
        line = lines.skip(6).limit(8).collect(Collectors.joining());
    }
```

Comment: What if I need to read multiple lines without specifying the line number but using for loop ?suppose like for(I=0;I<5;I++)reader.readLine();    how to read in such case?I am using java 8. Please help @Andriansoluk

Comment: If you use java 7, you can use the following code:
 String line = "";
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path))) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                line += br.readLine();
            }
        }
        System.out.println(line);

Comment: Suppose from 6th to 8th line I will read in another method,then shall i write the same code ? Or how to right there ? @Andian soluk

Comment: You can use the following code:
String line;
        try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get(path))) {
            line = lines.skip(6).limit(8).collect(Collectors.joining());
        }

Comment: @MadhusmitaSahoo answer updated. Have you fixed your problem?

Comment: Hii. Yes .it's fixed. Thanks alot.